# Facebook API Video Views

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the views of a video on my Facebook page.

My request:

```
{object-id}/insights/post_video_views_organic
```

But instead of data I get the following error back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (insights) on node type (Video)", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

I haven´t really worked with the Facebook API in the past so I cant really translate this error message.
(I am using the Graph API  Explorer)

Comment: @CoreyH What error are you getting? This should be working, as long as the user has given you read_insights permission. The answer below is also correct, the object id is the id of the object i.e. `{pageid_objectid}/insights`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding the id of your facebook page (which you can retrieve through the Graph API or [here](http://findmyfbid.com/))  to the start of the object id, followed by an underscore ('_') then the object id of the video.

Comment: Thanks, now the OAuthException is gone, but the data fields are empty. Any idea why?
"data": []

Comment: How many likes has your page got? It needs to have a minimum of 30 likes before Facebook will show insights for the page and any posts on it. (see here: https://www.facebook.com/business/products/pages#insights)

Comment: 2 Million likes. That shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried requesting just {object-id}/insights? Do you get any data? Have you debugged your access token? Does it have the read_insights permission?

Comment: @alexoakley1 So glad you answered this! Haven't been able to find this anywhere in Facebook's docs. In fact, the docs appear to state we should *not* use the `<page_id>_<object_id>` method, even though it's the only one that works. "The Graph API object {post-id} needs to be specified in the same format returned by the API call to fetch a list of page posts - do not attempt to split or combine other IDs to form a post ID" (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/insights)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the trick with the "_" - where in FB docs is this mentioned?

Comment: It isn't mentioned in the docs. I think I guessed it because somewhere else in the Graph API the post_id is returned including the `_`

Comment: Does this only work for your own videos, or for public videos? I can't get <page_id>_<post_id>/insights/post_video_views or /video_insights

Comment: @cfgm only for your own videos, and only when your page has more than 30 likes

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "{object-id}/insights/post_video_views_organic".

Use  "{post-id}/insights/post_video_views_organic" . You will get the metrics.

The "post-id" is post id of that video post.

Comment: Did you actually try this? It returns the same error as the original post.